# How to copy a table and change all id's inside a div adding a prefix with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `table` with some `tr` elements each one has a unique ID.

Now I need to copy all these elements inside a new div `list-player-songs` and change all `tr` ID's adding a prefix.

In the snippet below I did it but how can I change all ID's for my `tr` elements adding a prefix? Just to change from `<tr id="track251">` to something like `<tr id="my_track251">`.

```js
$('#list-player-songs').html($('.sortable').html());
```

```css
table {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
table td {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Original table</h3>
<table>
  <tbody class="sortable">
    <tr id="track251">       
      <td><div data-track-name="love.mp3" id="play251"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url251">love</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track241">       
      <td><div data-track-name="hate.mp3" id="play241"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url241">hate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track233">       
      <td><div data-track-name="think.mp3" id="play233"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url233">think</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Copied elements</h3>
<div id="list-player-songs"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it (:

```js
var $newTable = $('table.copyable:first').clone();
$newTable.removeClass('copyable');
$newTable
  .find('tr')
  .each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'my_'+$(this).attr('id'));
  });

$('#list-player-songs').html('');
$newTable.appendTo($('#list-player-songs'));

// debug
$('#list-player-songs>table tr').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
table.copyable {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
table td {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Original table</h3>
<table class="copyable">
  <tbody class="sortable">
    <tr id="track251">       
      <td><div data-track-name="love.mp3" id="play251"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url251">love</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track241">       
      <td><div data-track-name="hate.mp3" id="play241"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url241">hate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="track233">       
      <td><div data-track-name="think.mp3" id="play233"></div></td>
        <td id="song-url233">think</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Copied elements</h3>
<div id="list-player-songs"></div>

<hr/>
<br/><br/><br/>
```

The reason of why I'm cloning it and appending to div that is cleaned before appending: is **to keep all possible event handlers that was possibly binded to elements of original table**.